# ReactJS - Click event fires after second click

Tags: reactjs

Am trying to go over Adam Freeman's book - Pro React 16 and find that the following code updates state of counter after first click.
First click, nothing happens
Second click on things work as expected
What am I missing?
Or is the code incorrect?

This is listing 11.6 from book

```
//Simple Button
import React, {Component} from 'react';
    export class SimpleButton extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            counter: 0,
            hasButtonBeenClicked: false
        }
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick} className={this.props.className} 
                    disabled={this.props.disabled==="true" || this.props.disabled === true}  >
                {this.props.text} {this.state.counter} {this.state.hasButtonBeenClicked && <div>Button Clicked!</div>}
            </button>
        )
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({
            counter: this.state.counter + 1,
            hasButtonBeenClicked: true
        });
        this.props.callback();
    }       
}



//Sumamry component
import React from 'react';
import {SimpleButton} from './SimpleButton';

export function Summary(props){
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <td> {props.index + 1} </td>           
            <td> { props.name }  </td>  
            <td> {props.name.length } </td> 
            <td>
                <SimpleButton className="btn btn-warning btn-sm m-1" callback={ props.reverseCallback }  text={`Reverse (${props.name})`}   />
                <SimpleButton className="btn btn-info btn-sm m-1" callback={ () => props.promoteCallback(props.name) } text={`Promote (${props.name})`}  />
            </td>           
        </React.Fragment>
                
    );
}



import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React  from 'react';
import { Summary } from './Summary';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

let names=["Bob", "Alice", "Dora"];

function reverseNames(){
  names.reverse();
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
}


function promoteName(name){
  names = [name, ...names.filter(val => val !== name)];
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
}

function App() {
  return ( <table className="table table-sm table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr><th>#</th><th>Name</th><th>Letters</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        { 
             names.map( (name,index) => 
             <tr key={name}><Summary index={index} name={name} 
              reverseCallback={reverseNames} 
              promoteCallback={promoteName} /> </tr>) 
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
export default App;
```

What am I missing?
Or is the code incorrect?

This is listing 11.6 from book

[image: Edit dry-flower-bnrcy]

Expected Behavior:
Clicking on Promote button will promote row to top position,
Clicking on Reverse button will reverse the order of rows

Comment: Why do you have 2 `ReactDOM.render` in your app?

Comment: This is just a sample example. Will not likely happen in real world. There are 2 different event handlers that call render(). So this is all good. No worries there

Answer (score 0):

### **You have a few typos or mistakes in your code**

**In your `reverseNames` and `promoteName` function you put this:**

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

So you are trying to unexpectedly render the whole `App` component while React event handler has not finished yet.

This lead to unexpected behaviour as you saw in the OP.

It's expected to have only one `root` render DOM in your root file of your React App.

---

You might also want to move the `handleClick` before your render function because it will not be [unreachable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Stmt_after_return) after that return function:

**Here is the fixed version of your code:**

[image: Edit immutable-pond-2nse5]

Comment: Don't think the placement of method has anything to do with error. You can certainly try creating a new app and plug the three Components I've provided and see for yourself

Comment: I tried to place your given code and did a few correction as in the example and it works well. Or Am I míunderstanding something from you?

Comment: I copied your code on my project and it behaves in the same manner as my original code. If you click Promote Button, the row gets promoted but counter does not increment the first time

Comment: Did you try to open my codesanbox example? I don't see the issue you listed there.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance here. really appreciate it.
Looked at your solution which seems to have a different structure than the book example. So I uploaded files per the example in book and see the same error on codesanbox

Comment: I put my sample code link to sandbox in my OP

Comment: I see your problem now, That was a part of my fix from the original answer. I updated my answer. Please see if it's helpful to you.

Comment: I think I missed providing the expected behavior. I've updated the OP now with that info. Those render() in event handlers are needed to update the order of rows in the table. That's how the book has them.

Comment: The problem seems far from your first posts. Please help to raise another question about that.

Comment: Not sure how that is. The problem remains the same. With the same code, the error is the same. Removing the 2 lines is modifying the behavior.

Comment: Ya, It might be some technique that I've known yet. But to render the whole App in eventHandler is strange to me.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned earlier, this is a just a sample example from the book, am sure things would be different in real world applications. Any how thanks for your efforts. At least we know where the issue lies. Am surprised why other people who followed the book didn't come across this issue. Could it be a react api changes over versions?

Comment: It's hard to tell since I haven't read it yet.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that React enabled strict mode after the book was published

So changing index.js code from

```js
ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode> <App /> </React.StrictMode>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

to:

```js
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

fixed the issue.

and following is another, better solution from author

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Summary } from "./Summary";


export default function App() {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const incrementCounter = (increment) => setCounter(counter + increment);

    const [names, setNames] = useState(["Bob", "Alice", "Dora"]);

    function reverseNames() {
        setNames(names => names.reverse());
    }
    
    function promoteName(name) {
        setNames(names => [name, ...names.filter(val => val !== name)]);
    }

    return (
        <table className="table table-sm table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>#</th><th>Name</th><th>Letters</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            { names.map((name, index) => 
                <tr key={ name }>
                <Summary index={ index } name={ name } 
                    reverseCallback={ reverseNames } 
                    promoteCallback={ promoteName } 
                    counter={counter}
                    incrementCallback={incrementCounter}
                />
                </tr>
            )}
        </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```